# How do I implement MDL table within a card and get the table to scroll?

Tags: css, material-design, material-design-lite

I am trying to duplicate the UI here: http://www.google.com/design/spec/components/data-tables.html#data-tables-tables-within-cards

```
<div class="mdl-grid">
  <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--12-col">
    <div class="mdl-card mdl-shadow--4dp" style="width:100%">
      <div class="mdl-card__title">
        <h2 class="mdl-card__title-text">Header</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="mdl-card__supporting-text">
        <table class="mdl-data-table mdl-js-data-table mdl-shadow--2dp">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th></th>
              <th></th>
              <th></th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

1. How do I get card container's width to wrap around the table?
2. When the screen is small and the table is too long, how do I get the table to scroll within the card? Or even get the card to scroll in the page?

I am also unsure how to get this configuration to work:

```
------------------
|    8    |   4   |
------------------
```

With a table within a card inside the 8 and the 4 grid. However I think if I can get it to stretch over a 12 grid it will work for 8/4.

Comment: Is this pretty close to your example code : https://jsfiddle.net/9caz307g/ ? It's a bit unclear what you are actually wanting to do and how it relates back to the mdl page provided (beyond the page mentioning the concept of table within a card).

Comment: Yes, that's what I have as well in my code snippet. However, the container of the card doesn't conform to the width of the table - there is empty space to the right of the table). Also, if the table is 800px, and the screen is 400px, then the table doesn't scroll to the right, it just gets cut off.

Comment: I added `overflow: auto` to the `.mdl-card__supporting-text` div, this seems to make it so that horizontal scrolling works.  https://jsfiddle.net/9caz307g/1/

Comment: And `fit-content` will inform the outer div to be the width of the contained elements. https://jsfiddle.net/9caz307g/2/